# Difference between default routes

Tags: route

In my routing table (`ip route show` command), I've got the following entries:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.3.1 dev tun0
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

What is the difference between `0.0.0.0` and `default`? All default traffic is currently being routed through `tun0`, but if both lines have the same purpose, shouldn't the second line take precedence over the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A routing table entry requires a prefix length, ie. 0.0.0.0 **/1** in your case.

That entry matches only 0.0.0.0 through 127.255.255.255 (with 127.0.0.0/8 being non-routable as loopback range - thx @tontongerrit), so it's *not* a default route (that needs to match anything: 0.0.0.0 **/0**).

Using 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 in combination as a practical default route is a trick used with some VPN clients to point into a tunnel interface, so they don't have to remove your previous default route, pointing to the Internet. Since /1 prefixes are longer than the /0 prefix they take precedence.

Answer (score 3):

In routing, the more specific route (= the higher netmask value - the number behind the "/") takes precedence over the less specific route (lower netmask value). The default route, as stated above, has a netmask of /0. It is the lowest possible number, and it is the solution of last resort, if there is no more specific prefix in the routing table for a specific IP address, then traffic will be routed there.

0.0.0.0/1 covers 0.0.0.1 to 126.255.255.255 (not 127/8 which would typically refer to loopback IPs), and that route will be preferred over 0.0.0.0/0 (= default) if your destination IP address falls into the former range, simply because that prefix is more specific.