# Is `0.0.0.0/1` a valid IP address? If so, what does it indicate?

Tags: ipv4, networking, ip-address

I know that `0.0.0.0/0` represents a default route.
But I would like to understand what does `0.0.0.0/1` represents? Is it even a valid thing in networking?

Comment: see also https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/78785/25437

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is no valid IP *address*, regardless of prefix length. `0.0.0.0/0` as prefix matches any address, so it's used for the default route. Also, `0.0.0.0` is the *unspecified address* used in many APIs, indicating 'all local addresses'.

A `0.0.0.0/1` *prefix* matches any address from `0.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255` (practically `1.0.0.0` to `126.255.255.255`;  `0.0.0.0/8` is reserved for IANA special use and generally invalid, `127.0.0.0/8` is reserved for local loopback) - if that makes sense for you. I've seen at least one instance of crude 'load balancing' with two WAN uplinks where one was used for `0.0.0.0/1` and the other for `128.0.0.0/1`.

`0.0.0.0/8` and `0.0.0.0/32` specifically are reserved by [RFC 1122 section 3.2.1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122#page-29).

Comment: So the CIDR representation - `0.0.0.0/1` is practically used to represent an IP addresses range - `1.0.0.0` to `126.255.255.255`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I've made that clearer in the answer.

Comment: So `0.0.0.0/0` is the only CIDR representation which is considered as default route, correct?

Comment: `0.0.0.0/0` is the only prefix that matches *any* address, so yes.

Comment: I've also seen the CIDR pair `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` being using to apply a reversible route to `0.0.0.0/0`. This is typically done on `vpn-up/down.sh` scripts.

Comment: I thought reserving the .0 network address was considered obsolete. Is there a different reason why 0.0.0.0 specifically is invalid?

Comment: @user253751 With a prefix shorter than /24, the .0 address might not be anything special. It's the all-host-bits-zero address that's largely unusable with IPv4.

Comment: @Zac67 I meant the all-host-bits-zero address.

Comment: @user253751: It's inverse broadcast. You fill in 0.0.0.0 as a source IP address when you don't have an IP address yet.

Comment: Also should be noted, 0.0.0.0 in many networking APIs is used to specify "default network adaptor" when passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 21):

Zac is muddying the waters by excluding 0.0.0.0/8 and 127.0.0.0/8. While addresses in those two prefixes should never *appear on the wire*, 0.0.0.0/1 does cover them. The slash notation works the same for zero and one as it does for any number from 0 to 32, inclusive. "*The number of bits that matter*." One bit means 0-127, and 128-255; since you stated 0.0.0.0/1, it's the former [addresses 0.0.0.0 through 127.255.255.255, or in hex 00000000 - 7FFFFFFF]

It's a common trick of VPN software to use 0/1 and 128/1 routes as *more specific* than the (0/0) default route, without having to muck with other processes (eg. DHCP - if you mess with the routes DHCP installed, it will reinstall them when the lease renews.)

(But otherwise, yes, 0.0.0.0 is not a legal interface address.)

Comment: I would add that the pair of CIDRs allow you to "override" `0.0.0.0/0` without "overwriting" you `0.0.0.0/0` route.

Comment: That's what the second paragraph says.

Answer (score 6):

0.0.0.0/1 is not an IP address per-se, it's the combination of an IP address and a prefix length in CIDR notation. It represents the range of addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255.

There are a few places it might crop-up.

1. It's the CIDR notation for the block of addresses that were formerly known as class A (class B is 128.0.0.0/2, class C is 192.0.0.0/3 class D is 224.0.0.0/4 and class E is 240.0.0.0/4) .
2. As Zac97 suggests it may be used as a crude approach to load balancing, with 0.0.0.0/1 pointed at one link and 128.0.0.0/1 pointed at another link to use each link for (very roughly) half of destinations.
3. Some VPN software, notably openvpn, uses a pair of routes for 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 to effectively override the default gateway without modifying or removing it.